# Package not found despite being in package list file

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, apt

I'm trying to install a package called `kibana` from the ElasticSearch repository.

On both a trusty and a precise box, I've added this (and GPG keys) to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/logstash.list`:

```
deb http://packages.elasticsearch.org/logstash/1.5/debian stable main
deb http://packages.elasticsearch.org/kibana/4.1/debian stable main
```

Following that, I ran `apt-get update` as root on both boxes.

On trusty, I can then do this:

```
stwalkerster@logstash:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ apt-cache search kibana
kibana - no description given
stwalkerster@logstash:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$
```

On precise, however, the package appears to be missing:

```
root@spearow:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# apt-cache search kibana
root@spearow:/etc/apt/sources.list.d#
```

The content of `/var/lib/apt/lists/packages.elasticsearch.org_kibana_4.1_debian_dists_stable_main_binary-i386_Packages` on both machines is this - clearly showing the existence of a package called `kibana`:

```
Package: kibana
Priority: extra
Section: default
Installed-Size: 40948
Maintainer: <jls@crinkle>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 4.1.1
Filename: pool/main/k/kibana/kibana_4.1.1_amd64.deb
Size: 11859414
MD5sum: bf413bcd914f9a2ece6e4b3e65c377fa
SHA1: 6108605f2c0d539e0e4debbebced7e25d62b141d
SHA256: ce1f475a8f61cb3525f60e8ee2e40b3414d125dce85f1555de3041cbf97f82c1
SHA512: ec4f17d4ad13289118f4d20000b85e6adac451b71a2092f4ed5ea98f5c542624577209c0f1ed8eaf66b515a9577eb5dc41fb8c16feac43c8bef5405badcd62a7
Description: no description given
License: unknown
Vendor: jls@crinkle
Homepage: http://example.com/no-uri-given
```

There's no mention of any restrictions for precise/trusty in the package description.

Why is apt unable to find the package which appears to exist in the lists? What can I do to install this package?

Comment: O.o why is an `amd64` package being listed in the `Packages` file for (apparently) `i386`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out that the trusty machine is `amd64`, the precise machine is `i386`, and the package repository only has an `amd64` package published, despite actually being architecture-independent (it's a Java application), hence why it doesn't appear in the package repository for the first machine.

I ended up building my own package for this.